# ICU upgrade for intl extension on zend server ce macosx

Tags: php, macos, icu, zend-server, zend-server-ce

Where do I install the new version of icu for intl ext on zend server ce macosx?

I tried as described on readme file but it installed it in /usr/local/lib and zend server is in /usr/local/zend
Zend phpInfo still shows the old one.

How do I get it to work with zend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found great article in http://devzone.zend.com/1442/compiling-php-extensions-with-zend-server/ . worked for ubuntu 10.04.3 so also should work for mac:

1. Install php sources from zend repository
2. install/update your libicu-dev and libicu42
3. cd /usr/local/zend/share/php-source/php-5.3.7RC4/ext/intl/
4. /usr/local/zend/bin/phpize
5. ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/zend/bin/php-config
6. make
7. make install